# How to set a timer that keeps extending itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have build a popup with a timer. When the timer ends I want it to extend itself with another day. I have gone so far that it extends itself with 1 day for 1 time but then it quits.

Maybe you have any idea on how to proceed?

Thanks!

```
//Make countdown

var setInfiniteTime = '{{ $actiepopup->infiniteTime }}';

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Set the date we're counting down to

    // Get todays date and time
    var currentDate = new Date().getTime();

    // get countdown time
    var countDownDate = new Date(countDownTimeUntil).getTime();

    // console.log('countdowndateBefore' + countDownDate);

    // check in infinite time is set
    if (setInfiniteTime == 'Yes') {
        if (currentDate >= countDownDate) {

            // var i;
            // for (var i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {                    
            var countDownDate = new Date(countDownTimeUntil).getTime() + 86400000;
            //   console.log(i);
            // }
        }
    }

    // console.log('currentdate' + currentDate);
    // console.log('countdowndate' + countDownDate);

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - currentDate;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the result in the element with id="countdown"
    $("#countdown").text(days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

    // If the count down is finished, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        $("#countdown").text("Actie beeïndigd");
    }
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```

Hope you have enough information!

Comment: Maybe try to adjust [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bgeh9rfv/) somehow, so people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

[SetInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)

Also, just an advice, if you use boolean statements, just use `true` or `false` since it's way easier to work with

```
if (setInfiniteTime) { 
  setInterval(() => {
    var countDownDate = new Date(countDownTimeUntil).getTime() + 86400000
  }, 86400000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Correct me if im wrong but when i use setInterval it will not work because the script will be executed everytime the page loads. So it will reset the interval.. The popup will be shown in a webshop so there will be alot of interaction.

Comment: Then it's an entirely different scenario and requires either storing today's date in a session, against which a conditional check is performed, or storing variable server-side and making checks against it.